# Questions about Iterator Interface

Tags: java, interface, iterator, iterable

i'm studyng the basic interface and classes of the Java.util package. Now the interface Set is a subclass of Collection and Iterable, so Set have the Iterator moudle. So why i use a reference of the Iterator Interface?

```
    Iterator<String> iterx = x.iterator();
```

Iteratr is also a interface. But i haven't see any relation about the Iterable interface and the Iterator interface. Iterable have a moudle that is named Iterator. it would not be more correct to write

```
Iterable.Iterator iterx = x.iterator();
```

Because x.iterator call the moudle that Set have inherited by Iterable, and don't call the Iterator interface.

What i don't have understand?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but the qualified class name (`java.lang.Iterable`) that you write into your code has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: An iterator method (with result of type `Iterator`) is what a class that implements `Iterable` must provide.

Answer (score 0):

The Iterable interface says that a particular Collection is iterable, which means you can iterate over it by using Iterator.

It has only one method, which is iterator() returns an Iterator. Any collection e.g. List which implements Iterable provides implementation of iterator() method.

Iterator is also an interface which defines the iteration process it provides next(), hasNext() and remove() method which can be used to control the iteration, access the element and remove it.

Comment: yes ok, but how can comunicate the Iterator interface whit my object? The Iterator interface and the Iterable interface haven't any relation. Should not iterable call the iterator interface?

Comment: Create an inner class to implement Iterator just like ArrayList does

Answer (score 0):

You use `Iterator<String>` for the same reason you use `String` in

```
String stringx = x.toString()
```

the *method* (correct name for "module") declares that it returns you an object of that type. Methods can return any unrelated type and you'll have to adjust and use the variable type they give you.

`Iterator` is conceptually related to `Iterable` but they don't inherit from each other or so. And it's actually just convention that the `Iterator` grants you access to the same data as the `Iterable` that produced it.

But the design / convention for `Iterator` is that you can iterate *once* in the lifetime of an iterator over the collection of items (repeating `hasNext()`? Ok give `next()`! over and over until there is no next.). If you want to iterate again you'll have to get a fresh `Iterator`. And that's the responsibility of `Iterable`: It can produce a fresh `Iterator` every time you ask it.